# motorola MC3190 Bricked after changing registry value, change it back

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, motorola

I accidently bricked a MC3190 by running the following .reg file on it:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\Sip]
"DefaultIm"=""
```

(default was {42429667-ae04-11d0-a4f8-00aa00a749b9})

(I was trying to get the menu button in internet explorer in the bottom right to dissapear)

now when i start it up it first shows the Motorola MC3100 series logo and after 10-15 seconds (when it normally would show the windows starting up thing) the screen turns white. is there a way to change back the registry? (without having to do a full factory reset, if possible) The device is/was running windows mobile 6.5.

Comment: If it connect to ActiveSync while the screen turns white, you might put the default .reg in \Application\Startup and try rebooting the device.

Comment: @Martheen thats how I've been updating the registry before because i purpously disabled the menu buttons, but since it doesn't start up correctly, the activesync doesn't kick in and connect to my desktop. Also when I did it that way before it showed a popup that made a sound and asked for confirmation, and I see none of that. (even from the .reg that i had there beforehand). When i connect the device now I get a popup from windows that the USB-device is not recognised.

Comment: Welp, your only option now is to contact Motorola/your distributor. Being corporate device you have better chance to get dedicated response.

Comment: @Martheen guess a full reset it will be :(

Answer (score 1):

Normally all these devices support a Clean Boot key sequence on startup or being re-flashed with a prepared sd card in there memory slot.

The keys to hold or press on power up differ from OEM to OEM and from model to model.

For the MC3190 it seems you need to download a package and hopefully put it on the sdc card for autoload: https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/XU-EN/Resolution?solutionId=98048&redirectForm=search&searchQuery=%3FsearchType%3Dsimple%26searchTerm%3Dmc3100%20clean%20boot

Another side says you need to hold the left scan button during power up until a msg is shown. But this may depend on the Cleaner package.

Best will be to contact Motorola support...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The instructions from the link you send me say that I need to navigate on the device to these files and then run them, in other words (I think) I need to have the device working. I'm not entirely sure if I need the link you send me, or this one: https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/XU-EN/Resolution?solutionId=98393

Comment: Try a re-flash of the device or different keys hold during power up.